# Getting runtime error while trying to connect mysql from java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module "deployment.Sample.war:main" from Service Module Loader].
```

The above one is my error message.

I have included `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar` in my `class path` and it is shown in the `libraries` as well.

I am using `JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final server` to run it. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Add the module ref to the jboss deployment structure as a depends

Comment: Did you add the mysql-connector to Deployment Assembly?

Comment: Resolved it. Added the jar to the WEB_INF/lib folder as well and it is able to pick it up now.

Comment: Could you add code which shows how are you using driver?